# Почему не срабатывает getElementByID для input?

Tags: javascript, angular2, typescript

В разметке есть поле ввода:

```
<input _ngcontent-c0="" class="input" type="text" id="inp_city_333" style="display: none;">
```

в компоненте я получаю значение этого поля так:

```
let newVal = (document.getElementById('inp_city_' + id) as HTMLInputElement).value;
```

В этом случае всё ок.

Вопрос в том, почему я не могу в компоненте получить значение поля так:

```
let newVal = document.getElementById('inp_city_' + id).value;
```

Консоль выводит следующее сообщение об ошибке:

> Property 'value' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.

Comment: потому что в определении `getElementById` возвращаемым типом указан `HTMLElement`, а у этого типа **нет** свойства value

Comment: Что-то не понимаю. Какие типы могут быть у нативного js? Ведь document.getElementById это не ts, он должен работать в любом случае

Comment: Так он то и работает. Просто потом происходит преобразование. Ну а дальше уже всё написано. У меня другой вопрос, "Зачем это в контроллере?"

Comment: Судя по коду у вас не нативный js

Comment: @cyklop77, у нативного js и нет. Но ты ведь его и не используешь. Ты же собираешь этот код с помощью typescript, значит **весь код** считается typescript кодом, следовательно для всех случаев добавлены определения с конкретными типами.

Comment: _Ведь document.getElementById это не ts, он должен работать в любом случае_ - не используй компилятор typescript и все заработает